# 'use of undeclared identifier 'completedWithResult''

Tags: objective-c, xcode, push-notification, quickblox

When I try to enter this code, Xcode says me 'use of undeclared identifier 'completedWithResult''. This is with the code for Push Notifications on Quickblox. There is a piece of code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    /// Set QuickBlox credentials (You must create application in admin.quickblox.com)
    [QBSettings setApplicationID:XX];
    [QBSettings setAuthorizationKey:@"XX"];
    [QBSettings setAuthorizationSecret:@"XX"];
    //
    // If you use Push Notifications - you have to use lines bellow when you upload your application to Apple Store or create AdHoc.
    //

    [QBSettings useProductionEnvironmentForPushNotifications:YES];

    QBASessionCreationRequest *extendedAuthRequest = [QBASessionCreationRequest request];
    extendedAuthRequest.devicePlatorm = DevicePlatformiOS;
    extendedAuthRequest.deviceUDID = [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier];
    extendedAuthRequest.userLogin = @"yourUserLogin";
    extendedAuthRequest.userPassword = @"yourUserPassword";

    [QBAuth createSessionWithExtendedRequest:extendedAuthRequest delegate:self];

    // QuickBlox queries delegate
    - (void)completedWithResult:(Result *)result{
        if(result.success){

            // Create session result
            if([result isKindOfClass:QBAAuthSessionCreationResult.class]){
                // register for receive push notifications
                [QBMessages TRegisterSubscriptionWithDelegate:self];

                // Register for receive push notifications result
            }else if([result isKindOfClass:QBMRegisterSubscriptionTaskResult.class]){
                // Congrats! Now you can receive Push Notifications!
            }
        }
    }
```

The error is on this line:

```
 // QuickBlox queries delegate
        - (void)completedWithResult:(Result *)result{
            if(result.success){
```

It says 'use of undeclared identifier 'completedWithResult''

Please someone can help? Thanks!

Comment: You may want to remove your app secret from this code example.

Answer (score 4):

You're implementing a method *inside* of an other method. That's not allowed in Objective-C. You probably just missed the closing parenthesis of the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method. Close it with `}` above the second (`completedWithResult:`) method.

Comment: Add a `}` above the line `// QuickBlox queries delegate`...

Comment: You didn't include that code in your question. So actually you didn't forget the closing `}`. You just implemented a method inside of an other method, as I said. Put `completedWithResult:` outside of the `application:didFinishLaunching`.

Comment: I don't know how I could better explain. Select, cut, paste, done. Pick up an Objective-C book and read it

Answer (score 2):

You can't implement a method inside a method in Objective-C. Make sure you implement the method inside the class and not another method.

If you didn't figure it out yet, the delegation pattern is a simple but important part of the Cocoa framework: put you'r method inside the delegate class and the other compenents of you'r code (QBAuth in this case) will call it later.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't notice that DrummerB just said that.